# cakephp 2.0 & Translate Behaviour

Tags: php, cakephp, translation, cakephp-2.0

I have a model named 'Country' with the database table named 'countries'.

The Country Model is as follows:

```
<?
class Country extends CountryAppModel {     
    public $name = 'Country';
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Translate' => array('title', 'description')
    );
}
?>
```

Quoting the CakeBook 2.0 (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html)

> When defining fields for TranslateBehavior to translate, be sure to omit those fields from the translated model’s schema. If you leave the fields in, there can be issues when retrieving data with fallback locales.

so I deleted the title & description fields from the 'countries' table.  Of course, I have the i18n table created by command line (to be sure I have the updated version)

When I try to save using the following code, nothing happens though, no saving in the DB:

```
$this->Country->locale = $_POST['language'];
$this->Country->create();
$this->Country->save($this->request->data)
```

any ideas what am I doing wrong??

I went through the save() method of the 'Model' class and it's not executing any update/create commands because there are no other fields in the schema of the 'countries' table apart from the primaryKey (id) - shouldn't the save() cater for the translatable fields too?

Comment: Are you sure `$_POST['language'];` contains the correct value? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @drHannibalLecter - $_POST['language'] has something like 'it_IT'.  Something weird I noticed is that if I add a field with the countries table, that is not translatable & I set it to an empty string, it works fine...

Comment: Only if you set it to an empty string, or just any value? BTW, you shouldn't use `$_POST`, you have `$this->request->data` in your controllers.

Comment: any other value - well if I use `$_POST['language']` or `$this->request->data["language"]`, it's the same thing. but yes infact I am using `$this->request->data` when saving instead of setting each field like `$this->Country->set('title', $this->request->data['title']);`

Comment: I haven't checked the code, but this certainly looks like a cake limitation of a sort. Probably the easiest thing to do is simply create a dummy field in your `countries` table and always set it to some hardcoded value in beforeSave or something like that. Wish I could help you more, but that seems to be the best I can do.

Comment: no worries @drHannibalLecter. cheers for your help anyway ;)